# How to do a counter of specific words in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, counter

Hey guys I am developing a project where I have 4 questions where someone can evaluate as (great, good, regular, and poor), and after that I would need to check how many people voted as great, how many voted as good, regular, and poor, for each of the 4 questions. So I would like to make a count to check the .txt and count how many times the word (great, good, regular, and poor) apears on it. I was trying to do it like in Python, where you only need a dictionary (or a counter) and simply do something like:
dict["great"] += 1

However, it isn't possible to do so in Java. Does anyone know any method that would be similar to this one in Java, or another way to do it simply (without having to create a lot of variables to save each question's answer).

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't possible to do it in Java?

Comment: It's pretty much the same idea, except that you need a `Map` in Java

Comment: Really? I was trying to do that with the Map's class but I've got some error message, guess I was doing it wrong rofl, I'll take a look on that, thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java 8 the [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method was added to the `Map` interface. It may be a bit more complicated than in python, but it's probably the closest it gets to the python code:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

String rating = ...

map.compute(rating, (key, oldValue) -> ((oldValue == null) ? 1 : oldValue+1));
```

The lambda expression passed as second parameter to `compute` receives the old value the key was mapped to as second parameter or `null`, if there was no mapping.

Answer (score 2):

This is 100% possible in Java.

Use a HashMap to store the values.

For example:

```
HashMap counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

counts.put("great", 0);
counts.put("good", 0);
counts.put("regular", 0);
counts.put("poor", 0);
```

Now, suppose you read in a string `input`.

To increase the counter, do :

```
counts.put(input, counts.get(input) + 1);
```

This will increase the counter in that position by 1.

Use `counts.get(input)` to get the counter of input string.

Comment: what if the key doesn't exist? like in python: test[a] = test.get(a,0) + 1; I tried the above and got an error, do I just handle with a try-except?

Comment: You can use something like counts.put(input, counts.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);